# Help with proving this inequality

Tags: inequality

Prove that for $x_i > 0$ and $x_i$ distinct such that $x_1 < x_2... < x_{2n+1}$,

$\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{2n + 1} (-1)^{i+1} x_i \leq \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{i+1} (x_i)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: If we have $n=1$ and $x_1=2$ and $x_2=x_3=1$ we have on the left
$1\cdot 2 -1+1$ and on the right side  $(1\cdot 2 -1+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which is less than the right hand side.

If you take a closer look your equation says $f(n,x) \leq f(n,x)^{\frac1n} $ which does not hold in general

Comment: Sorry. $x_i$ should be ordered.

Comment: Induction? Yes?

Comment: I tried that but I got stuck.

Comment: You might have to formulate your induction hypothesis in a clever way-- see what different forms it can take on.

Answer (score 2):

To use induction, it is more convenient to prove the following more general inequality:

$$\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{2n + 1} (-1)^{i+1} x_i\right)^m \leq\sum_{i = 1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{i+1} x_i^m. \tag{1}$$ 
The original inequality is just the a special case of $(1)$ when $m=n$.

Let us fix $m$ and prove $(1)$ inductively on $n$. When $n=0$, $(1)$ is trivially true. Denote 
$$a=\sum_{i = 1}^{2n -1} (-1)^{i+1}x_i,\quad b=x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}\quad and\quad c=x_{2n}.$$ By induction, assume that 
$$a^m\le \sum_{i = 1}^{2n-1} (-1)^{i+1} x_i^m.$$
Then to obtain $(1)$, it suffices to prove that
$$(a+b)^m+c^m\le a^m+(b+c)^m.\tag{2}$$

Noting that $a=x_{2n-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_{2i}-x_{2i-1})<x_{2n-1}<c$, $(2)$ follows from binomial theorem immediately, which completes the induction.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I didn't see that I made an error in the question.

Comment: @Victor: Never mind. I have updated my answer.